# Unable to lock for exclusive access. Another application may

Tags: assembly, boot

Quando estou fazendo o debug do boot.bin pelo nasm ele retorna o seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

boot.asm:

```
BITS 16 ; The mode we are running in (default for every modern computer)
ORG 0x7c00 ; the origin, the boot loader is always loaded at 7C00 by the BIOS
jmp Main ; Jump the a label called "Main"

;IN: si=string, OUT:-
Print:
lodsb ; Load string byte (Load a character that's in si into al)
cmp al, 0 ; If that character is equal to "0" jump to done
je Done

mov ah, 0eh ; Set parameters for interrupt 10
int 10h ; Call the interrupt
jmp Print ; Loop back in Print to print the next character

Done: 
ret ; return back to the place we where called

Main:
mov si, msg ; Move the data of msg into si
call Print ; Call the Print label
cli 
hlt ; Halt the system

msg db 'Hello World!',0 ; Define the variable msg to a string

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; make sure the file is 512 bytes

dw 0xAA55 ; Last 2 bytes need to be AA55
```

Como faço para resolver?
Sintaxe que estou usando: debug boot.bin

Comment: No `main`, antes de chamar o `Print`, você não deveria definir os valores de `bh` e `bl`?

Comment: Não é um problema no código, testei aqui (Win 7), o problema ocorre quando você usa o comando `debug` do Windows, O *drive* `A` é um volume? o que acontece se você clicar em *Ignorar*?

Comment: Se o que você quer é depurar o código, use um depurador como o *WinDBG*, ou *OllyDBG*.

Comment: O drive A é um disquete criado pelo VFD. Se eu clicar em ignorar, a mensagem de erro abre novamente.

Comment: Tem certeza que não há nada *montado* nesse volume?